# Dotnet 6 dotnet-ef fails after install

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I'm on a Pop!_OS 22.04 machine and trying to setup `dotnet` and `dotnet-ef` for Entity Framework.

I am running into trouble getting `dotnet-ef` to work. I have ran

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
```

but when I go to try to use it I get an error:

> You must install .NET to run this application.
>
> App: /home/chewy/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-ef
> Architecture: x64
> App host version: 6.0.10
> .NET location: Not found
>
> Learn about runtime installation:
> https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed
>
> Download the .NET runtime:
> https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?missing_runtime=true&arch=x64&rid=pop.22.04-x64&apphost_version=6.0.10

I'm not sure why it cannot find my existing dotnet install

```
dotnet --list-sdks
6.0.402 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
```

I also saw on other posts a potential fix was to add the tools directory to the path like

```
cat .bashrc
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.dotnet/tools/"
```

But that hasn't resolved the problem. Any idea what is going on with my install?

Comment: Do you have any runtimes installed? Run `dotnet --info`.

Comment: I do, running that command gives me back - 
.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.10 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.10 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Comment: Just [follow the docs and install the appropriate runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu#2204): `apt-get install -y aspnetcore-runtime-6.0`. It looks like you have stuff halfway installed.

Comment: I purged all my dotnet packages, sudo apt-get remove *dotnet*
 and followed along those docs but got the same result when trying to run dotnet-ef, dotnet itself works fine

Comment: dotnet-apphost-pack-6.0/hirsute,now 6.0.10-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
dotnet-host/hirsute,now 6.0.10-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
dotnet-hostfxr-6.0/hirsute,now 6.0.10-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
dotnet-runtime-6.0/hirsute,now 6.0.10-1 amd64 [installed]
dotnet-runtime-deps-6.0/hirsute,now 6.0.10-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
dotnet-sdk-6.0/hirsute,now 6.0.402-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
dotnet-targeting-pack-6.0/hirsute,now 6.0.10-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
dotnet6/jammy-security,jammy-updates,now 6.0.110-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 amd64 [installed]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [this documentation](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/7699) I was able to get everything working successfully.

> Do the following:
>
> ```
> Remove all .NET packages
> ```
>
> sudo apt remove dotnet* sudo apt remove aspnetcore*
>
> ```
> Delete PMC repository from APT, using any of the typical methods, for instance by deleting the repo .list file
> ```
>
> sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list
>
> ```
> Update APT
> ```
>
> sudo apt update
>
> ```
> Install .NET SDK 6.0
> ```
>
> sudo apt install dotnet-sdk-6.0

I'm guessing something installed incorrectly from the first time I attempted the install leaving everything in that Mixed state scenario 1

Comment: Unfortunately, the apt path is officially not supported on arm64...

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74895147/how-to-fix-dotnet-ef-tool-net-location-not-found)

In short, add a `DOTNET_ROOT` variable to your environment. For me, I used the .NET [scripted installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-scripted-manual#scripted-install) and added this to `~/.bashrc`:

```
export DOTNET_ROOT=~/.dotnet
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and discovered in the `dotnet --info` that the path to the dotnet executable was wrong; also the DOTNET_ROOT was wrong.

So there are two more useful commands:

```
 dotnet --list-runtimes 
 dotnet --info
```

Answer (score 0):

I was on macOS and got this error while running `dotnet ef add migration`.

The solution for me was install the given .NET Runtime in the **error message** itself, using the link provided.