# How to fix dotnet ef tool, .NET Location not found

Tags: asp.net-core, ubuntu, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I created a .net core 7 project using the entity framework core. Well, at that time I installed .net core 6 so my global ef tool was still version 6, then I updated to version 7. Here I had a problem, it said that I had not installed the framework. I decide to uninstall dotnet. Then I reinstalled sdk 7 and global ef tools. And new error appear. I try reinstall many times. But still like this, now I can't use the ef tool.

```
This is dotnet --info

    .NET SDK:
 Version:   7.0.101
 Commit:    bb24aafa11

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  22.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         ubuntu.22.04-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.101/

Host:
  Version:      7.0.1
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       97203d38ba

.NET SDKs installed:
  7.0.101 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.1 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.1 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Other architectures found:
  None

Environment variables:
  DOTNET_ROOT       [/usr/lib/dotnet]

global.json file:
  Not found

Learn more:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/info

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/download
```

And this is the error,

```
You must install .NET to run this application.

App: /home/apriza/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-ef
Architecture: x64
App host version: 7.0.1
.NET location: Not found

Learn about runtime installation:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed

Download the .NET runtime:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?missing_runtime=true&arch=x64&rid=ubuntu.22.04-x64&apphost_version=7.0.1
```

Answer (score 27):

I found the answer; I change the Root dotnet env which is in `/usr/share/dotnet` for dotnet 7.

```
export `DOTNET_ROOT=/usr/share/dotnet`
```

Comment: If you visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-environment-variables#net-sdk-and-cli-environment-variables, they mention that this location could vary depending on the source and system.

Comment: thanks, @B3zaleel e.g. it looks like the [installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-scripted-manual#scripted-install) puts it at `$HOME/.dotnet` for me

Comment: In my case it was `export DOTNET_ROOT=/usr/local/share/dotnet`

Comment: It's still working for .NET 8. Btw in order to use it from bash on VS Code I had to add it on my user's  `.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 2):

Linux user can set the `DOTNET_ROOT` environment variable to point to their .NET SDK installation directory:

**1. Choose an Editing Method:**

There are two main ways to set environment variables in Linux:

- **Editing Shell Profile:** This method makes the change persistent across terminal sessions. It involves modifying a configuration file like `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`.
- **Setting in Terminal:** This method only affects the current terminal session. You can directly set the variable using the `export` command in the terminal.

**2. Editing Shell Profile (Persistent):**

- Open your shell profile using a text editor. Common profiles include:

  - Bash: `.bashrc` (located in your home directory)
  - Zsh: `.zshrc` (located in your home directory)
- Add the following line to the end of the file, replacing `$HOME` with your actual home directory path:

```bash
export DOTNET_ROOT=$HOME/.dotnet
```

- Save the changes and close the editor.
- **Source the Profile (Optional):**

  - To make the changes take effect immediately in the current terminal session, run the following command:

    ```bash
    source ~/.bashrc  # For bash profile
    source ~/.zshrc  # For zsh profile
    ```

**3. Setting in Terminal (Current Session):**

- Open a terminal window.
- Run the following command, replacing `$HOME` with your actual home directory path:

```bash
export DOTNET_ROOT=$HOME/.dotnet
```

This sets the `DOTNET_ROOT` variable only for the current terminal session. Once you close the terminal, the variable will be unset.

**Important Notes:**

- Make sure to replace `$HOME` with your actual home directory path if it's different from the default location.
- You might need to restart any running applications that rely on the .NET SDK for the changes to take effect fully.