# .NET SDK not found issue in Asp.Net Core application

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core

So, I have simple Asp.Net Core 6 MVC web app which is showing this kind of error when running this command:

## Command:

`dotnet ef migrations add Initial`

## Error:

[image]

## What I have tried so far:

I came across just the same issue [here in the stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74895147/how-to-fix-dotnet-ef-tool-net-location-not-found), I tried it by defining *DOTNET_ROOT* path in `.zshenv` file `export "DOTNET_ROOT=/usr/local/share/dotnet/”` (I'm sure that the exact location is indicated) and it didn't help. But the error message was different this time:

[image]

---

## Some assumptions:

I highly think that the problem is related to my laptop's CPU architecture. I mean I'm using Mac with M2 chip and error messages above say something about incompatibility. Also I am including the current state of my `.zshenv` file here:
[image]
This error is also showing up when I'm trying to use libman package: `libman init -p cdnjs`
Thanks for the answer in advance!

Comment: It looks like you have installed .NET for M2 (arm64) but the ef tool needs .NET for Intel (x64). Try installing that to see if it helps. https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-7.0.107-macos-x64-installer