# .NET location: Not found error in Raspberry OS Lite

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Recently I am about to run an Avalonia program in Raspberry OS Lite.

It works well if running with self-contained.

When it run with framework dependent, it reports this error:

```
admin@raspberrypi:~/Test1 $ sudo ./AvaloniaApplication1 --drm
You must install .NET to run this application.

App: /home/admin/Test1/AvaloniaApplication1
Architecture: arm64
App host version: 7.0.7
.NET location: Not found

Learn about runtime installation:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed

Download the .NET runtime:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?missing_runtime=true&arch=arm64&rid=debian.11-arm64&apphost_version=7.0.7
```

And here is the dotnet --info of the device:

```
admin@raspberrypi:~/Test1 $ dotnet --info
.NET SDK:
 Version:   7.0.305
 Commit:    98e1b6c381

Runtime EnDebianent:
 OS Name:     debian
 OS Version:  11
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         debian.11-arm64
 Base Path:   /home/admin/.dotnet/sdk/7.0.305/

Host:
  Version:      7.0.8
  Architecture: arm64
  Commit:       4b0550942d

.NET SDKs installed:
  7.0.305 [/home/admin/.dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.8 [/home/admin/.dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.8 [/home/admin/.dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Other architectures found:
  None

Environment variables:
  DOTNET_ROOT       [/home/admin/.dotnet]

global.json file:
  Not found

Learn more:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/info

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/download
```

And here is the struct of directory:
[image]

It's worth mentioning that I can't install .net using `curl -sSL https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.sh | bash`. I download the SDK manually and refer to this tutorial https://levelup.gitconnected.com/install-the-net-6-0-sdk-on-a-raspberry-pi-in-two-easy-steps-27993c1bd68d installed.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix dotnet ef tool, .NET Location not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74895147/how-to-fix-dotnet-ef-tool-net-location-not-found)

Comment: @Robsdedude I did what it said before while do not work any.

Comment: Just go double check: did you adjust the path in the exported variable to point to your different install directory? Because in the linked question it was somewhere in `/usr/shared` or such, but for you it would be in `/home/admin/.dotnet`.

Comment: Another angle to approach this: you are running the application with sudo. Did you check that the env var is correctly set with sudo? Try `sudo echo $DOTNET_ROOT` or `sudo dotnet --info`.